# ReactJS -- Overlay Button not Clickable when placed above a List

Tags: html, css, reactjs, overlay, material-ui

Please see the Code Example in Code Sandbox I have created

[image: Edit W7qNgVnlQ]

I want the button action of the Floating Button to fire. But instead the Action assigned to the ListItem is triggered. 
Any Ideas solution will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more a markup/styling issue than a js problem. The easiest thing you can do is set a z-index on the overflow container.

```
const overlay = {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 30,
    right: 10,
    zIndex: 100
}
```

This makes your example working, but maybe there are better markup solutions to solve your problem.